# @WebfluxTest failed with subresources, eg posts/post id/comments

Tags: spring, spring-test, project-reactor, spring-webflux, spring-boot-test

Whens I used `@WebFluxTest` to test my controller in a mock environment, and try to test `Comment` subresouces of `Post` aka **/posts/1/comments**, failed. But the tests of the **/posts** related endpoints work.

`PostController` codes is like the following, the complete codes is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/angular-spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/server/src/main/java/com/example/demo/PostController.java):

```
@RestController()
@RequestMapping(value = "/posts")
class PostController {

    private final PostRepository posts;

    private final CommentRepository comments;

    public PostController(PostRepository posts, CommentRepository comments) {
        this.posts = posts;
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    //other methods for /posts endpoints

    @GetMapping("/{id}/comments")
    public Flux<Comment> getCommentsOf(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        return this.comments.findByPost(new PostId(id));
    }

    @PostMapping("/{id}/comments")
    public Mono<Comment> createCommentsOf(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestBody @Valid CommentForm form) {
        Comment comment = Comment.builder()
            .post(new PostId(id))
            .content(form.getContent())
            .build();

        return this.comments.save(comment);
    }

}
```

`PostControllerTests` looks like the following, the complete codes is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/angular-spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/server/src/test/java/com/example/demo/PostControllerTest.java):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebFluxTest(controllers = PostController.class)
public class PostControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    WebTestClient client;

    @MockBean
    PostRepository posts;

    @MockBean
    CommentRepository comments;
    // other tests
    @Test
    public void getCommentsByPostId_shouldBeOk() {
        given(comments.findByPost(new PostId("1")))
            .willReturn(Flux.just(Comment.builder().id("comment-id-1").content("comment of my first post").build()));

        client.get().uri("/posts/1/comments").exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk()
            .expectBody()
            .jsonPath("$[0].id").isEqualTo("comment-id-1")
            .jsonPath("$[0].content").isEqualTo("comment of my first post");

        verify(this.comments, times(1)).findByPost(any(PostId.class));
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(this.comments);

    }

    @Test
    public void createCommentOfPost_shouldBeOk() {

        Comment comment = Comment.builder().id("comment-id-1").content("content of my first post").createdDate(LocalDateTime.now()).build();
        given(comments.save(comment))
            .willReturn(Mono.just(comment));

        CommentForm form = CommentForm.builder().content("comment of my first post").build();
        client.post().uri("/posts/1/comments").body(BodyInserters.fromObject(form))
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk()
            .expectBody()
            .jsonPath("$.id").isEqualTo("comment-id-1")
            .jsonPath("$.content").isEqualTo("content of my first post")
            .jsonPath("$.createdDate").isNotEmpty();

        verify(this.comments, times(1)).save(any(Comment.class));
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(this.comments);
    }

}
```

When I ran `getCommentsByPostId_shouldBeOk` test, and got exception:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$[0].id"

at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:247)
at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.assertValue(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:100)
at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.JsonPathAssertions.isEqualTo(JsonPathAssertions.java:49)
at com.example.demo.PostControllerTest.getCommentsByPostId_shouldBeOk(PostControllerTest.java:198)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: No results for path: $[0]['id']
at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.EvaluationContextImpl.getValue(EvaluationContextImpl.java:133)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:187)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:345)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:329)
at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:244)
... 33 more
```

I have tried the comments endpionts by **curl**, and also wrote [integration tests for it](https://github.com/hantsy/angular-spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/server/src/test/java/com/example/demo/IntegrationTests.java#L131-L147), it works.

**Updated**: When I changed the test `getCommentsByPostId_shouldBeOk` to the following:

```
EntityExchangeResult<byte[]>  results = client.get().uri("/posts/1/comments").exchange()
        .expectStatus().isOk()
        .expectBody().returnResult();

log.debug("return results::" + new String(results.getResponseBody()));
```

It printed an empty json array:

```
2018-01-07 11:42:52.385 DEBUG 17492 --- [           main] com.example.demo.PostControllerTest      : return results::[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The cause

The problem was in your mockito mock preparation

```
given(comments.findByPost(new PostId("1")))
        .willReturn(Flux.just(...));
```

Also, note, in your case `PostId`'s `#equals` and `#hashcode` is formed incorrectly, so `new PostId("1").eqauls(new PostId("1"))` returns `false`

## The fix

Try to fix your mockito preparation in a next way, and then all expectation will be passed

```
 given(comments.findByPost(any()))
            .willReturn(Flux.just(Comment.builder().id("comment-id-1").content("comment of my first post").build()));

        client.get()
              .uri("/posts/1/comments")
              .exchange()
              .expectStatus().isOk()
              .expectBody()
              .jsonPath("$[0].id").isEqualTo("comment-id-1")
              .jsonPath("$[0].content").isEqualTo("comment of my first post");

        verify(this.comments, times(1)).findByPost(any(PostId.class));
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(this.comments);
```

### Or

Add annotation `@EqualsAndHashCode` to your `PostId` class so your current code will work

Comment: @Hantsy, I have create a PR to your repo

Comment: Thanks. But why I need to pass an `any` instead of a real parameter in given statement? And all tests before this in the test class works well. And I also used Mockito like this way in before projects.

Comment: @Hantsy, Actually, it seems that your `PostId` is formed incorrectly because, `new PostId("1").equals(new PostId("1"))` returns `false`. That is why given(....(new PostId("1")) will never be called with that parameter

Comment: @Hatnsy, you missed `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotation

Comment: Thanks for explaining this.

Comment: I used `@Data` instead, the `getCommentsByPostId_shouldBeOk()` works. But I do not know why the `createCommentOfPost_shouldBeOk() ` is still failed if using a real parameter, I am not sure if the `save` parameter is the same instance of the return result(in Mono).